# reliable way to give all read/write access recursively in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, command-line, permissions, chmod

What is the most reliable way to give all users read/write privileges for a given directory, all of its subdirectories, and files in CentOS 7?

In an eclipse web application project that uses Maven, I am getting the following compilation error in the pom.xml:

```
Parent of resource: /home/user/workspace/MinimalDbaseExample/target/m2e-wtp is marked as read-only.
```

Since this sounds like a permissions issue, I typed in the following in the CentOS 7 terminal:

```
chmod -R ugo+rw /home/user/workspace/MinimalDbaseExample/target/
```

And I also tried:

```
chmod -R 0777 /home/user/workspace/MinimalDbaseExample
```

But eclipse is still showing the compilation error, even after multiple `Project clean`  and `Maven update` operations. However, I am able to import the same zipped project file into a Windows version of eclipse, and there is no compilation error related to file permissions in the Windows version, so this causes me to wonder if perhaps my above `chmod` statements did not actually open up the file permissions in the CentOS 7 machine.

Is there a better statement syntax that can reliably open up read write permissions to all users for the given directory and all its recursive subdirectories and files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipse but maybe the read-only is something defined in the project rather than the file system? Another possibility is that some files are not owned by you so you cannot chmod them, but then chmod should have complained.

Comment: @BjornMunch I am root.

Comment: You should also consider whether `SELinux` is causing this.  You can temporarily disable it with `sudo setenforce 0`.

Comment: Also, try `namei -lx /home/user/workspace/MinimalDbaseExample/target/m2e-wtp` which will shown you what's mounted where as well as permissions for the whole directory tree from root to leaf-node.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thank you very much for looking into this.  Please see **EDIT** to my OP describing the results.  I am still experiencing the same problem.  What else can I try?

Comment: You can try disabling `selinux` using the command I posted.  Also, check for file attributes - use `lsattr <path>` against the directories that are failing.  You should see something similar to `-------------e--`.  If there is an `i` in there, then the directory is immutable.  Fix it with `chattr -i <path>` (as root).

Comment: @garethTheRed Please see my new **EDIT#2**.  Is there something else I can try?  I am trying to either resolve or completely rule out file permissions as a possible cause of this.

Comment: You could always remove the `=` from the `setenforce` command - `sudo setenforce 0` (no equals sign).

Comment: @garethTheRed I tried `setenforce 0`.  This disabled SELinux (which may have already been disabled).  But I am still getting the same error in eclipse.  I am looking for a way to be able to isolate the problem to maven/eclipse.  I want to rule out that it is any kind of CentOS 7 file permissions problem.

Comment: @garethTheRed The solution was to export the project to a different eclipse workspace on the same centos devbox.  Your help enabled me to rule out possible server level permissions causes.  You actually started helping before the person who posted their help as an answer started helping.  Thank you very much for helping me isolate the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said you wanted to grant read and write permissions to all subdirectories and files under: `/home/user/workspace/MinimalDbaseExample` ... right?

Octal `0777` permissions grant `rwxrwxrwx` symbolically.

Octal `0755` permissions grant `rwxr-xr-x` symbolically.

Octal `0666` permissions grant `rw-rw-rw-` symbolically.

To set read/write/execute permissions to the `/home/user/workspace/MinimalDbaseExample` directory and all files and folders within it, choose which permission set you want, and do the following as an example:

1) Make your present working directory : `/home/user/workspace`

2) Type: `chmod -R 0777 MinimalDbaseExample/`

Following this procedure exactly, grants the folder `MinimalDbaseExample/` and all files and subdirectories therein `0777/drwxrwxrwx` permissions.

I tested this setting up some dummy directories under my '~' directory and verified it worked.

Credit goes to this thread, but it should not be at all this complex... I hope you make progress.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt

Comment: I revised my post you could try this instead, as @garethTheRed suggests, it should be quite straightforward unless SELinux or some other layer is in some way making this more complex then usual.

Comment: The solution was to move the project to a different eclipse workspace on the same CentOS devbox, and let eclipse manage the permissions.

Comment: Thank y0u and +1.  This problem emerged on a different machine.  In the new situation, your revised two step solution above worked.